# Unexpected build Errors when adding a Specflow Feature file

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2019, specflow

When adding a Specflow Feature File to my testproject I'm getting some build errors.

1. Could not find a reference to Specflow in the project
2. Use MsBuild Generation instead of Specflow Single File Generator

I read and googled a lot about this error but still I'm not able to solve this problem.

- why the feature file is generated with properties CustomTool: SpecflowSingleFileGenerator altough in the options for Specflow in Visualstudio the option EnableSingleFileGeneration is 'false'??
- when I change SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator to reset to default all build errors disappear but when I rebuild the project without changing anything the build error reappear.

I'm busy for the whole day now with this but I'm out of options. Upgrading tot a higher Specflow version also didn't solved it. Working with Visual studio 2019, Specflow 2.4.1, Specflow Tools Ms Build Generator 2.4.1

[image]

Comment: Try removing SpecFlowSingleGenerator from properties for feature files. And try build.

Comment: See the second bullet abbove,  I tried, the build errors disappeared but after rebuild they are back again

Comment: can you try to set SpecFlowSingleGenerator to false, and then remove specflow from VS extensions. Restart VS, Install specflow, do again VS restart and try build.

Comment: I will try tomorrow.

Comment: one more thing, on your picture, SpecFlowSingleGenerator is set to false, but in properties for feature file CustomTool equals SpecFlowSingleGenerator

Comment: Yes that curious and unexpected, it's my question on the first bullet.

Comment: There were issues with that option. You should keep empty CustomTool property in feature files (when use MSBuild for generation). Or try with reinstallin SpecFlow (but set value to false before uninstall).

Comment: Succeeded to solve the issue by creating a new project. But now the problem is that no tests are genrated in Test Explorer

Comment: Enable SpecflowFile generation to TRUE

Comment: Not sure f you have already, but install the extension 'nunit test explorer'